# default context for all pages Django

Tags: python, django, templates

I was wondering if there's any way of sending a default context for all pages in django, such as user is always passed to the template regardless of other context, for my particular case i want to send context for navbar such as category and sub category to all pages without having to send in all the views.
TIA

Comment: Create context processor

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a context processor. Create a **context_processors.py** in any app, I suggest doing it on your main app. And here you can create context dictionaries. Like so:

```
from product.models import SubCategory, Category


def add_variable_to_context(request):
    return {
        'subCategories': SubCategory.objects.order_by('id').all(),
        'categories': Category.objects.order_by("id").all(),
    }
```

Add this line to your **TEMPLATES** in ***settings.py*** to call the created context processor

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'context_processors': [
        ....
        'yourAppName.context_processors.add_variable_to_context',
        ....
    ],
},
```

Now you can call your created context dictionaries in your ***base.html***