# Why doesn't my 'home' page recognize 'object_list' in views?The specific template of CBV only does

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a navbar template and I want to make it **dynamic**.
When I want to do this in the template, nothing happens:

```
{% for platform in object_list %}
    <li><a href="#">{{platform.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

This code only works in the platform.html file
but I want to show the navbar in all of my html files

[It is in platform.html(platform URL) and it should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhmSr.png)

[And this one is in home url but it is an empty subnav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUnD0.png)

> this is my models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Platform(models.Model):
    PLATFORM_CHOICES = (
        ('PC', 'PC'),
        ('PS', 'playstation'),
        ('XBOX', 'Xbox'),
        ('NS', 'nintendo switch'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=PLATFORM_CHOICES, verbose_name= "platform")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "platform"
        verbose_name_plural = "platforms"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
    platform = models.ManyToManyField(Platform)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "game"
        verbose_name_plural = "games"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

> this is my views:

```
from .models import Game, Platform
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, TemplateView

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html')

class GameList(ListView):
    template_name = "blog/game.html"
    model = Game
    games = Game.objects.all()
    context = {
        'games': games
    }

class GameDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = "blog/game_detail.html"
    def get_object(self):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        return get_object_or_404(Game.objects.all(), slug=slug)

class PlatformList(ListView):
    template_name = "blog/platform.html"
    model = Platform
    platforms = Platform.objects.all()
    context = {
        'platforms': platforms
    }
```

> This is my home.html file:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#mobile_menu" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">GROUP.COM</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mobile_menu">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Platforms<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                {% for platform in object_list %}
                                    <li><a href="#">{{platform.title}}</a></li>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li>
                                <form action="" class="navbar-form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="search" name="search" id="" placeholder="Search Anything Here..." class="form-control">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login / Sign Up <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any suggestion how I can fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [default context for all pages Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60515797/default-context-for-all-pages-django)

Comment: No because it is different.He has created a specific model for subcategory.But my model is a category that its title is subcategory of that

Comment: Read the answer again, research about context processors if you still don't understand. It **does** answer your question as you want a way to pass some data to all templates and context processors are how you do that. (You should learn to understand the answer rather than focus on the irrelevant details, their they wanted to pass those objects so they passed them you would pass whatever you want...)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat OMGGG I took another look at it and replaced the names and finally it worked!! thank you so much